# Ruby hash map with key that contains '-'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hashmap

How can I add hash map element with a key that contains "-"?

Like this:

```
<%= button_to_function 'Cancel','cancelRemove("cancelEmail")', :data-dismiss=>'modal', :class=>'btn' %>
```

I get an error:

> undefined local variable or method 'dismiss' for `#<ActionView::Base:0x3482fed>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `:'data-dismiss'` works, with `data` attributes you can also do

`:data => { :dismiss => 'modal' }`

Additional `data`-prefixed html attributes can be included in the same hash. So for example on another link you might do:

`:data => { :remote => true, :method => 'delete' }`

which would add to the link the html attributes `data-remote="true" data-method="delete"`.

While the hash syntax is less compact for a single attribute, it's nice when you've got more than one html5 data attribute. And it's arguably a bit more rails-ish.

Answer (score 1):

Just rename it to:

```
<%= button_to_function 'Cancel','cancelRemove("cancelEmail")', :'data-dismiss'=>'modal', :class=>'btn' %>
```